# Endianness followed in NASM 64 bit programming

Tags: nasm, x86-64

I have 2 situations :

I.

```
 arr dq 1234567887654321H

 mov rsi,arr 

 mov rbx,[rsi]
```

Now, as we know that rsi always points to 1 byte of location in memory and x86 follows little-endian. Does rsi points to 21H and then this 21 gets into rbx or the complete value in arr gets transfered to rbx ?

II.

```
  tempbuff resb 16
  arr resb 1234567887654321H
  mov rbx,qword[arr]
  mov rsi,tempbuff
  mov [rsi],rbx
```

Above statements are taken from different sections and combined here so as to focus on important details.

Now, from the above statements, rbx stores the entire contents of arr.

rsi points to 1st memory location of tempbuff. Then does the mov [rsi],rbx
stores the entire content of rbx to tempbuff OR does it simply stores the lowest 1 byte of rbx(here 21) into the the location pointed by rsi(1 byte location) ?

Comment: Have you tried running it?

Comment: mov rbx,[rsi] is storing the 64 bit content in rbx even when rsi points to 1 byte address.  I am not able to understand, why ?

Comment: Because `rbx` is a 64 bit register.

Comment: `Nasm` implicitly resolves memory size pointed by right hand side `,[r64]` based on left hand side target which is a `r64` in your case. So you have a 64bit address pointing to a 64bit value which will be moved to a 64 bit register. You can specify rhs pointer memory size explicitly with `,byte [r64]` `,word [r64]` etc.

Comment: @Kamil.S     So, acc. to your explanation, the transfer of data depends on what is the size of register that is present in LHS. And, if I specify type_specifier[reg] then the type_specifier sized data will move to destination (LHS) . Is that right now ?

But what about the second case ? How much of rbx goes in tempbuff through [rsi] because here also rsi points to one byte of tempbuff. I hope that the above logic doesn't hold in this case.

Comment: Correct, in your latter case the size of memory copied is fixed to your rhs register size (64bits == 8 bytes).

Comment: So, does 1 byte of rbx goes into [rsi] or the complete 64 bit ?

Comment: Whole rbx register value , 64bits

Comment: Well, if i write mov [rsi],al     and supposing that al stores 39H then this time the lowest 1 byte memory address of  tempbuff will store al but will  it change the rest 7 bytes of tempbuff or not ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168973/discussion-between-kamil-s-and-jacob).

Comment: @Kamil, since you were able to answer the question in chat, can you please put that into an answer?

Comment: rbx as the source or destination makes the operand-size for `mov` 64-bit.  Most disassemblers would show you a `qword ptr` on the memory operand if you assembled and disassembled.  You could have *easily* tested this.

Comment: @prl added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For case **1**:

```
mov rbx,[rsi]
```

`Nasm` implicitly resolves memory size pointed by right hand side `,[r64]` based on left hand side target which is a `r64`. Hence `rsi` is 64bit address pointing to a 64bit `[rsi]` value which will be moved to a 64 bit `rbx` register.
This could be explicitly stated in `Nasm` as

```
mov rbx,qword [rsi]
```

It implies the statement in the question 
*"rsi always points to 1 byte of location in memory"*
is **incorrect**. It would be **valid** for following instruction:

```
mov rbx,byte [rsi]
```

Where first encountered byte pointed by 64 bit `rsi` address will become `rbx` least significant byte.

For case **2**:

```
mov [rsi],rbx
```

Whole 64 bit `rbx` value is moved into memory pointed by 64 bit `rsi` address.

From the chat discussion I can draw conclusion OP's real doubt was about little endiannes affecting registers and memory.

```
exampleQuadWord dq 0102030405060708H ; this is represented in memory as 0807060504030201
exampleQWordWithByte dq 1 ; this is represented in memory as 0100000000000000
```

In a simplistic example

```
mov rbx,2
mov rsi, exampleQWordWithByte
mov [rsi],rbx
; exampleQWordWithByte in memory is now 0200000000000000
```